# Where can i find pip in linux to add it to my path? Python3.11.3

Tags: python, pip

I've installed Python 3.11.3 in my Linux machine, but every time I need to install an offline package or do something with pip I have to run it using:

> python3.11 -m pip install "package"

But I can't use it just with the command pip (without python3.11) like:

> pip install "package"

I've searched for it to add to my PATH but I only find in usr/local/bin/ (the folder I have in my PATH) a not folder type file that is the one of python3.11.3, am I missing something, where is the pip file located to add it to my PATH?

Thank you very much.

Edit:

When I try to run pip install something it tells me:

*bash: pip: command not found...*

Im using RHEL8, and I've created an alias for python to link it to my python3.11 version.

If I try **which pip** it gives me *No pip in (/usr/local/bin: .... etc*

From this Linux machine I **don't** have internet access, so I have to do everything offline.

Comment: What happens when you run `pip install package`. Can you edit your question and add the output this command?

Comment: Add info about which linux/desktop versions you are using. Try `which pip` or `which python`. These will give you the default installed python and pip executables. If you want to make your new installation your "default" one, you can set aliases, e.g. on ubuntu `alias python = <path to your new python, or simply python3.11>`... same for pip.

Comment: "I've created an alias" -- that can mean a few different things. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line in ~/.bashrc

```
alias pip='python3 -m pip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just utilize these commands

```bash
sudo yum update
sudo yum -y install python3-pip
```

You can also you `dnf` if that's what you use for package management.

Comment: I've edited my question, I dont have internet access from that linux machine. Would downloading the rpm work? And will that pip be linked to my python3.11.3 version (I have several versions installed) Thanks!

Comment: Follow @duaghk answer as that is simple and doesn't require you to handle additional packages. But if you wanna install `pip` without internet you can take a look at [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue myself, you need to locate your pip executable and not just the folder itself and add it to the "~/.bashrc" file.

After you save the changes close the terminal and open it again.
You should be able to use Pip after that with no Python3 prefix